# Error - Simple Encryption and Decryption - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, electron

I'm trying to develop some very simple code to encrypt and decrypt some simple text. The problem appears to be that when running the code the .final() of my createDecipherIV causes that error in the title to be produced.

I've attempted to toy with the various encoding (Binary vs Hex, base 64, etc.)

node: '10.15.3'

openssl: '1.1.0j'

This is an electron project, though I don't know what impact that might have

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); 
let sessionKey = crypto.randomBytes(256/8).toString('hex'); 

class encryption { 
    constructor() { 
        this.encryptionOptions = { 
            algorithm: 'aes-256-cbc',
            iv: crypto.randomBytes(16), 
            key: String, 
        }
    }
    encryptMem(memItem){
        this.encryptionOptions['key'] = Buffer.from(sessionKey,'hex'); 
        var cipher = crypto.createCipher(this.encryptionOptions['algorithm'], this.encryptionOptions['key'], this.encryptionOptions['iv']);
        var cipherText = cipher.update(memItem,'utf8','hex');
        cipherText += cipher.final('hex');
        return this.encryptionOptions['iv'].toString('hex') + cipherText;
    }
    decryptMem(memObject){
        this.encryptionOptions['key'] = Buffer.from(sessionKey,'hex'); 
        var _iv = Buffer.from(memObject.slice(0,32),'hex')
        var _data = memObject.slice(32)
        var _decode = crypto.createDecipheriv(this.encryptionOptions['algorithm'], this.encryptionOptions['key'], _iv); 
        var _decoded = _decode.update(_data,'hex','utf8'); 
        _decoded += _decode.final('utf8')
        return _decoded; 
    }
}
```

The sample code

```
e = new encryption 
encryption {encryptionOptions: {…}}
val = e.encryptMem("test") 
"adcd1f5876ca02a4420b61df5dfdaa9be3080108020df42dfc630951ffabe0ac"
e.decryptMem(val)
\lib\encrypt.js:25
internal/crypto/cipher.js:172 Uncaught Error: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT
    at Decipheriv.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:172)
    at encryption.decryptMem (\lib\encrypt.js:26)
    at <anonymous>:1:3
final @ internal/crypto/cipher.js:172
decryptMem @ \lib\encrypt.js:26
(anonymous) @ VM433:1
```

Where as it should simply return "test

**EDIT** As pointed out in the answer, createCipher needed to be changed to createCipheriv

The following is some shortened code that should also correctly create a new iv with every invocation of encryption, rather then with simply the invocation of the class

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); 
let sessionKey = crypto.randomBytes(256/8).toString('hex'); 

class encryption { 
    constructor(key = null){ 
        this.algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
        this.key = key || Buffer.from(sessionKey,'hex'); 
    }
    encrypt(plainText){
        var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);  
        var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(this.algorithm,this.key,iv);
        var cipherText = cipher.update(plainText,'utf8','hex') + cipher.final('hex');
        return iv.toString('hex') + cipherText;
    }
    decrypt(cipherText){
        var iv = Buffer.from(cipherText.slice(0,32),'hex');
        var data = cipherText.slice(32);
        var decode = crypto.createDecipheriv(this.algorithm,this.key,iv);
        var decoded = decode.update(data,'hex','utf8') + decode.final('utf8');
        return decoded; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
crypto.createCipher
```

Your block mode (CBC) requires an IV, but you're using `createCipher` instead of `createCipheriv`.  I assume this is a typo since you're using `createDecipheriv`.